# Local date in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, timestamp-with-timezone

I have records containing timestamps, and I want to be able to group by date (according to my local time zone).

The timestamps are already ISO 8601 strings (in the same local time zone with UTC offset specified). I tried using the SQLite `date` function, however it seems to only give UTC dates:

```
select date(time), time from mytable;

('2001-07-14', '2001-07-15 09:40:02.500000+10:00'),
('2001-07-14', '2001-07-15 09:39:38.500000+10:00'),
('2001-07-21', '2001-07-22 09:46:09.500000+10:00'),
...
```

In Postgres I would take a UTC timestamp and do something like `((mystring::timestamp at time zone 'UTC') at time zone 'AEST')::date`. I suppose if my timestamps are already expressed with my desired offset, I could just do a string truncation (i.e. `substr(time,1,10)`), but this seems much less readable code. Can SQLite generally convert timestamps to localised dates?

Answer (score 0):

Can try `date(time,'localtime')` provided that the target timezone is also currently the system local time zone (which is an awkward requirement).

Otherwise, `date(time, '+10 hours')`.